# Algorithm for inflating/decompressing partial gzip

Tags: javascript, algorithm, gzip, compression, inflate

I want to implement partial gzip decompression, i.e. inflating gzip chunk by chunk, in Javascript. Something like "zcat file.gz | head" in Linux. I'm looking for a good pseudocode.

The benefits of decompressing partial gzip are:

1. No need to decompress the whole large gzip file to get only line number 1000.
2. No need to finish retrieving the whole file to view/analyse only the first 10 lines.

According to [this](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html), once we get past several bytes of the header of a gzip file, we are on the "compressed blocks" and we can inflate ourselves (for example, using [this inflate algorithm](http://www.onicos.com/staff/iz/amuse/javascript/expert/inflate.txt)).

I have tried inflating several first bytes of the compressed blocks (i.e. first chunk, in any chunk size), and it worked! However, when I took second/third chunk, it didn't work. It seems that gzip-inflate algorithm needs several bytes before the chunk to inflate.

Question: What's the proper way of determining the start and stop byte positions of a gzip chunk to inflate/decompress?

**UPDATE:**

```
[31,139,8,8,222,44,65,84,0,3,118,101,114,97,46,116,120,116,0,172,92,217,114,227,58,140,125,191,95,49,85,19,219,241,110,237,187,68,136,73,232,84,205,211,20,223,231,255,255,98,136,133,178,72,185,251,206,195,168,59,137,183,116,17,34,128,115,112,0,182,250,254,239,255,126,164,69,94,21,183,228,63,126,255,43,73,255,167,72,154,172,77,219,164,77,210,44,107,218,228,145,36,255,153,220,211,127,192,106,208,198,90,99,140,213,218,90,109,141,198,63,214,128,6,0,99,232,53,247,22,224,107,248,142,123,205,253,112,95,248,171,198,0,255,138,123,170,255,57,255,243,252,253,253,125,126,253,254,206,239,175,113,134,89,254,42,112,223,213,172,148,2,247,165,234,94,241,149,224,19,122,241,31,245,178,34,141,173,200,243,226,141,21,90,203,114,44,184,7,110,177,238,57,91,129,230,209,130,181,51,140,22,108,0,112,217,238,85,67,230,186,63,248,25,180,194,25,241,107,12,89,1,193,250,225,245,0,196,14,103,3,208,37,235,87,131,252,44,221,87,54,212,107,43,178,216,138,186,201,82,180,34,13,172,176,160,105,43,220,98,241,31,182,180,104,90,178,123,203,173,148,63,129,47,210,142,128,230,109,113,191,227,126,11,47,103,14,90,97,126,233,114,235,155,112,161,19,200,210,213,200,183,95,205,115,79,207,1,23,13,170,27,217,136,81,165,170,115,134,92,200,20,128,75,122,94,91,145,199,86,84,69,134,70,84,225,86,0,222,95,116,34,205,27,129,14,131,94,130,15,12,26,133,159,68,107,12,25,73,59,65,246,88,254,77,247,174,51,98,248,50,95,198,124,27,190,199,48,184,175,227,4,189,226,91,78,223,239,106,192,187,15,227,212,3,140,254,229,82,85,227,216,186,231,106,68,51,218,161,237,215,70,20,145,17,89,145,21,206,136,52,244,39,203,222,129,222,174,113,15,240,66,199,210,228,92,24,52,228,105,120,239,105,15,208,106,247,58,217,109,157,55,97,96,97,84,60,201,157,126,213,250,154,82,247,109,55,29,31,147,114,247,187,169,6,188,231,170,234,219,214,133,66,62,14,109,94,214,197,227,114,169,93,104,220,149,122,212,215];
```

Above is the binarystring array of my example. Below is the header:

```
[31,139,8,8,222,44,65,84,0,3,118,101,114,97,46,116,120,116,0]
```

Any substring starting with 172 (right after the header) can be decompressed/inflated well. But when the substring is not from 172, I got nothing when I decompress/inflate. Maybe the String to be inflated MUST indeed be from that 172 position?

Comment: When you tried to unzip the second and subsequent chunks, are you *certain* that you were starting at the proper position? When you moved to the second chunk, did you inspect the header to see if it looked reasonable? What does, "it didn't work" mean? What error did you get? Are you certain that you implemented the inflate algorithm correctly? You need to give us more information before we can answer your question.

Comment: Yes, I'm certain. I'm aware of the header. The error is it returns nothing when decompressing (not an error per se). I'm not sure I implemented inflate algo correctly, but I've tried inflating several first bytes of the "compressed block" and it works. It just won't work if I don't start from the beginning of the compressed block. I have an example, just added on UPDATE, pls see above, thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot start decompressing from the middle of a deflate stream.  At least not without having decompressed the entire stream at least once before and building an index for random access.

First, the deflate format is inherently serial.  Compression is achieved in part with finding strings that match previous strings.  A match may refer before where you started, so you won't know what the uncompressed data is.  What's more, what is matched may have itself been a match, and that a match of something that preceded it, all the way back to the beginning of the file.

Second, the deflate format is inherently serial.  It is a format constructed of codes of a variable number of bits, with no markers to tell you where a code or block or anything starts.  There is no way to know where a deflate block begins just by looking somewhere in the middle of the sequence of bytes.  The only way to know where the blocks start is to decode all of the codes starting from the beginning of the deflate stream.

In order to build a random access index, you'd need to decompress the entire thing first and a) save the bit locations of the start of each block, and b) save the previous 32K of uncompressed data at each of those points to satisfy matches that appear in the block (32K is the maximum distance of a match).  Here is an [example of such code](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/zran.c).

There is no way to decompress starting from the middle of a deflate stream that you have never seen before.

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean that [GzipInputStream.read() and GzipInputStream.skipBytes()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/FilterInputStream.java#FilterInputStream.read%28byte%5B%5D%29) 1) decompress everything first (which I believe it's not), and 2) never decompress starting from the middle of deflate stream, although they say 'buffer'?

Comment: That is correct.  (What you believe in parentheses is not correct.)

Comment: Thanks very much for the enlightment!!